# Apache Superset for Vue developers

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuetify.js, apache-superset

We have used [Superset API](https://superset.apache.org/docs/api/) to fetch the dashboards and charts data into our web application.
We can able to perform CRUD operations on them.

http://localhost:8088/api/v1/chart/data

```
{
    custom_cache_timeout:   0
    datasource: {},
    force   :   true,
    form_data:  string,
    queries : [],
    result_format:  string,
    result_type :   string
}
```

Is there anyway to visualize above chart data in our Vue application?

Answer (score 0):

You can try apache echarts.

[Apache Echarts](https://echarts.apache.org/en/index.html)